# Convergence of $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \ln(1+\frac 1 {2^n})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Does $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1} \ln(\frac {2^n+1}{2^n})=\sum^\infty_{n=1} \ln(1+\frac 1 {2^n})$ converge?

Condensation, root, ratio and limit comparison tests don't help, I don't know what to do... Any hints please?

**Note:** no integral test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I disagree that the limit comparison doesn't help. Since the summands of the series are positive,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} 2^n \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{2^n}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\log(1 + x)}{x} = \frac{d}{dx}\bigg|_{x = 0} \log(1 + x) = 1,$$

and $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}$ converges, by limit comparison the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{2^n}\right)$ converges.

Comment: I think the $=$ there is wrong, did you use LHR?

Comment: @GinKin I used the substitution $x = 1/2^n$.

Comment: Ah I see, nice.

Answer (score 11):

Since $0< \ln (1+x) < x$ for $x>0$, then
$$ 0 < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln (1+2^{-n}) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} = 1 $$

Comment: +1 for being the only answer to use a specific inequality (and one that should always be in the toolkit) rather than 'fuzzy' (though admittedly rigorous) asymptotic estimates.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^n}{n}$$

This means $$\ln(1+x) = x + O(x^2)$$ as $x \to 0$.

Thus $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+2^{-n}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{2^n} + O\left(\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\right)\right)$$

Thus $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+2^{-n}) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} + C \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2n}}$$

Both of the sums are convergent on the right. So the original sum converges by the direct comparison test.

---

Another method is to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln(1+2^{-n})}{2^{-n}} = 1$. This follows from the definition of the derivative (or if you like, l'Hopital's rule).

Thus by the limit comparison test $\sum \ln(1+ 2^{-n})$ and $\sum 2^{-n}$ either both converge or they both diverge. We know the second converges since it is a geometric series, thus the original converges as well.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that, as $x \to 0$,$$
\ln(1+x) \sim x
$$ giving, as $n \to \infty$, $$
\ln\left(1+\frac 1 {2^ n}\right)\sim\frac 1 {2^ n}
$$ and by comparison your series is **convergent**.

Comment: Does using approximations considered rigorous?

Comment: @GinKin Here the series are positive.

Comment: But what is the justification to use an approximation? Isn't there a need to prove that they're approximately the same?

Comment: @GinKin This is not really an approximation, the notation $a_n\sim b_n$ means $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. It is a powerful rigorous tool, giving among other things $a_n \sim b_n$ implies $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are both convergent or both divergent if $a_n, \, b_n$ have constant sign. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Convergence is straightforward by comparison with $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n}=1$. Actually

$$ S=\sum_{n\geq 1}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n}\right) = \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^{nm}}=\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m(2^m-1)} $$
and
$$ S=\log\left(1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{q(n)}{2^n}\right) $$
where $q(n)$ [is the number of restricted partitions](http://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/PartitionsQ/introductions/Partitions/ShowAll.html) of the positive integer $n$ into a sum of distinct positive numbers that add up to $n$ when order does not matter and repetitions are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The series is positive and its general term is such that $\log{(1+\frac{1}{2^n})}\sim \frac{1}{2^n}$ and the RHS is the general term of a convergent series. Therefore the series we are looking at is convergent.

Comment: Is it considered rigorous to use an approximation? Isn't there a need to justify it?

Comment: It is not an approximation it is an equivalence in the Landau notation. It says $\lim \frac{f}{g}=1$ if we are dealing with positive sequences the series have the same nature